# Ruby from CodeAcademy CONTROL FLOW IN RUBY Dare to Compare

Tags: ruby

I need help because this didn't work. 
It gives an error message:

> (ruby):8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'

Make sure to put an expression after each `=!`.
Run:

```
(#) test_1 should be false
test_1 = 10 < 8

(#) test_2 = should be false
test_2 = 8 > 10

(#) test_3 = should be true
test_3 = 8 != 8
```

Comment: what you're supposed to type is just the part after the "should be false", e.g. you just type `test1 = 10 < 8`

Comment: I just try and still not working. (ruby):8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'

Comment: You are just supposed to ensure whether the following statement given is true or false

Answer (score 0):

What does `(#)` mean ?

You start a parenthesised expression `(` (everything in Ruby is an expression), then there is a comment `#) test_1 should be false`, then an expression `test_1 = 10 < 8`, then an inner parenthesised expression `(`, then a comment `#) test_2 = should be false`, etc, etc. But there are no closing parentheses, hence the error.

This works :

```
(#) test_1 should be false
test_1 = 10 < 8

(#) test_2 = should be false
test_2 = 8 > 10

(#) test_3 = should be true
test_3 = 8 != 8 
)))
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t_op.rb 
t_op.rb:2: warning: assigned but unused variable - test_1
t_op.rb:5: warning: assigned but unused variable - test_2
t_op.rb:8: warning: assigned but unused variable - test_3
```

Actually what you wanted to do is :

```
# test_1 should be false
test_1 = 10 < 8

# test_2 = should be false
test_2 = 8 > 10

# test_3 = should be true ????
test_3 = 8 != 8 

# test_4 = should be true
test_4 = 8 != 18

puts "test_1=#{test_1.inspect}"
puts "test_2=#{test_2.inspect}"
puts "test_3=#{test_3.inspect}"
puts "test_4=#{test_4.inspect}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
test_1=false
test_2=false
test_3=false
test_4=true
```